# Compare scala map values to a list and return default value for keys that don't exist in the list

Tags: scala, dictionary, hadoop, data-science

I am trying to compare a Scala HashMap's keys to a list of values, if the key doesn't exist in the list I need to update the Map's value to a default value of -1.

For example: 
Consider the following case:

List:

```
val pos = List("100","110")
```

Map:

```
scala> idSizeMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(100 -> 4240070722, 110 -> 611884363, 120 -> 1825405636, 130 -> 2194234, 72 -> 3685020648)
```

Using filterKeys I can do an intersection like operation

```
scala> val result = idSizeMap.filterKeys(pos.contains)
result: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(100 -> 4240070722, 110 -> 611884363)
```

But instead I also want the keys in the old map with the default value -1. 
Expected output:

```
Map(100 -> 4240070722, 110 -> 611884363, 120 -> -1, 130, -1, 72 -> -1)
```

Also I tried the following, which does the same operation as filterKeys:

```
var similarItems = Map[String, Long]()
similarItems: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map()

scala> for (eachpos <- pos) {
     |   if (!eidSizeMap.contains(eachpos)) similarItems += (eachpos -> -1)
     |   else
     |   similarItems += (eachpos -> eidSizeMap(eachpos))
     | }

scala> similarItems
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(100 -> 4240070722, 110 -> 611884363)
```

What is the most suitable Scala way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [`transform`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#transform[W](f:(K,V)=%3EW):CC[K,W])

```
idSizeMap.transform((k, v) => if (pos.contains(k)) v else -1)
```

which might be slightly shorter because keys are left untransformed.

Answer (score 4):

You can just `map` each of the entries and if the key is not in `pos` replace the value with the default:

```
idSizeMap.map{ case (k, v) => k -> (if (pos.contains(k)) v else -1) }
```